# Check if room is free (classroom booking)

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, excuse me for my poor English. I'm trying to select all rooms that are not reserved yet. The query seems to work most of the time, but sometimes it shows the room which has already been booked for the given time.

```
//Example input:
//$date = 2014-06-04;
//$begintime = 09:30;
//$endtime = 12:00;

$query = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM room
    WHERE room.id NOT IN  (
                            SELECT room_id
                            FROM reservation
                            WHERE reservation.begintime <= '{$date} {$begintime}'
                            AND reservation.endtime >= '{$date} {$endtime}'
                            )
    ");
```

What am I doing wrong? It's driving me crazy, just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

The begin and endtime are both DATETIME columns.

Comment: Most likely because of `'{$date} {$begintime}'` and the other one. Why not just setup your column as `DATETIME` so you'll use one variable?

Comment: Create comma seperated list from the second query and save it in a PHP variable and then use in in the IN clause.

Comment: Yes, also, we would need to see the output of your query after variables have been written

Comment: obviously... what happens if the new begintime falls between an existing begintime and the endtimes are fine? doublebook

Comment: Use `var_dump($query);` to see exactly how your query is being passed into DB. That will give you a good indication. Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: In your example, if there's an existing reservation from 10am to 11am, you'll double-book. Your time period logic is flawed.

Comment: I get no errors, var_dump gives me this:
object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(8)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: @JasonK They want you to vardump the SQL so put your `select * from...` in a variable called `$sql` and then `$query = $mysqli->query($sql)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the column types of the begin and end time, your comparisons might fail, but as indicated in the comments, your logic of comparing the times is wrong.

You need to compare the begin time to the end time and vice versa:

```
WHERE reservation.begintime <= '{$date} {$endtime}'
AND reservation.endtime >= '{$date} {$begintime}'
```

Apart from that, I don't know where the data comes from but to avoid sql injection, you'd better use a prepared statement instead of injecting php variables directly in your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

The way to check for double-booking is this:

If the existing reseveration starts at B0 (beginning 0) and ends at E0 (end 0), and the time period you want to check is from B1 to E1, then you want to check all existing reservations where:

```
(B0 < E1) && (B1 < E0)
```

These are collisions, double-bookings.

Answer (score -1):

As @d'alar'cop hinted at above, you need to change your query like so:

```
WHERE reservation.begintime >= '{$date} {$begintime}'
                            AND reservation.endtime <= '{$date} {$endtime}'
```

You want to find a reservation that is greater than the begin date, and less than the end date, not vis versa.

Also, instead of using separate columns, you will want to use a combined datetime column.

Comment: Well, that's only solving half (well maybe one-third) the problem!

Comment: Until we see the the result of var_dump($query), I think any response will be premature.